# How to sort a list of char[]?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, sorting

I have the following list:

```
List<char[]> list1 = new List<char[]>();
```

And I need to sort all the **`char[]`** elements on them. If I use `list1.Sort()` it says it cannot compare the elements, any idea how can I sort it?

I really need the list to be `char[]` not `string`.

Comment: do you need to sort every array individually or all arrays are sorted together ?

Comment: So you're wanting to sort the char array as thought it was a string, so ['A', 'B', 'C'] would be before ['A', 'C', 'B']?

Comment: It would really help if you'd give a short but complete example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Might not fast, but list1.OrderBy( x => new String(x) ) should do it.

Comment: how do you want to sort them? Can you please give an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you expect the `char[]` to have the exact behavior in sorting as a `string`, you could do this:

```
list1 = list1.OrderBy(x => new string(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: @Rawling: I guess that is the logical thing to do.

Comment: This doesn't sort the existing list referred to by the value of `list1`. It returns a new sequence, but it doesn't modify the existing list at all.

Comment: Still doesn't modify the existing list :p (not my DV by the way, I'm happy to wait until OP clarifies)

Comment: @Rawling: True. And about the downvote, I know you as a fair voter, so even if you did, I don't mind.

Comment: @Rawling: Also, about the 'if': OP says he doesn't want to use `string` as a data type. It seems he does intend to do a `string` like sorting, but that is just my 2 cents.

Comment: Looks like you chose... wisely :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use also use [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) as desired with the [approach of Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27445243/284240):

```
list1.Sort((chars1, chars2) => new string(chars1).CompareTo(new string(chars2)));
```

That does not need to create a new list.

Another way is to implement your own `IComparer<T>` for `Char[]`. This should work although it is certainly improvable and untested. The relevant part is the `Compare` method:

```
public class CharArrayComparer : IComparer<Char[]>, IEqualityComparer<Char[]>
{
    public CharArrayComparer() : this(false) {  }
    public CharArrayComparer(bool ignoreCase)
    {
        IgnoreCase = ignoreCase;
    }
    public bool IgnoreCase { get; set; }

    public int Compare(char[] x, char[] y)
    {
        if (x == null && y != null) return -1;
        if (y == null && x != null) return 1;
        if (y == null && x == null) return 0;
        int minLength = Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length);
        for(int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
        {
            char c1 = IgnoreCase ? char.ToUpperInvariant(x[i]) : x[i];
            char c2 = IgnoreCase ? char.ToUpperInvariant(y[i]) : y[i];
            if (c1 < c2) return -1;
            else if (c2 < c1) return 1;
        }

        return x.Length - y.Length;
    }

    public bool Equals(char[] x, char[] y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        if (x.Length != y.Length) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            char c1 = IgnoreCase ? char.ToUpperInvariant(x[i]) : x[i];
            char c2 = IgnoreCase ? char.ToUpperInvariant(y[i]) : y[i];
            if (c1 != c2) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(char[] chars)
    {
        if(chars == null) return 0;
        int hash = 17;
        unchecked
        {
            foreach (char c in chars)
            {
                if(IgnoreCase)
                    hash = hash * 31 + char.ToUpperInvariant(c).GetHashCode();
                else
                    hash = hash * 31 + c.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

It's easy to use in `List.Sort` or in many LINQ extension methods:

```
list1.Sort(new CharArrayComparer());
```

Comment: It does need to build more strings though... but I don't think there's an out-of-the-box in-place sort that can avoid that.

Comment: @Rawling: i've tried to implement one but it's yet not tested. Might be helpful anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - thanks for this solution - saved me a bunch of dev work. My only comment is you probably want to change the final return statement to the Compare function to something like "return x.Length - y.Length;" because if x & y share the same chars up to the min length, then the longer char array is comparatively  greater than the shorter one.

Answer (score 0):

for using **List.Sort()** the list elements should be **comparable** (implement comparable interface)
So if you have special compare I prefer to create a new class for the elements and with implementing Comparable Interface and overriding CompareTo method to your own comparing mechanism